# Парсер видео

Tags: php, парсер

Добрый день!

Мне нужна помощь в написании парсера. К примеру, раньше на my-hit.ru был jw player старой версии.Можно посмотреть [сохраненную страницу](http://hghltd.yandex.net/yandbtm?text=site%3Amy-hit.ru&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmy-hit.ru%2Ffilm%2F8998%2Fonline&fmode=inject&mime=html&l10n=ru&sign=4702ebd911f6d8dd18a1cc6d8c52942e&keyno=0) страницы и посмотреть исходник.

```
flashvars="file=http://a-11.my-hit.ru/data3/previews/8998.flv  это ссылка на фильм."
```

В парсере можно было написать так:

```
preg_match( "#flashvars\=['\"](.*?)['\"]#is", $content, $matches );
```

**Обратите внимание только на этот код:**  `#flashvars\=['\"](.*?)['\"]#is`

Так у меня получалось парсить ссылку, но с выходом новой 6 версией jw плеера, май хитовцы поставили его сразу же и ссылки на сайте теперь нужно другим путем парсить, есть ли у кого какие идеи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На странице есть запись:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>jwplayer('hit-video').setup({file: 'http://b-62.my-hit.ru/data0/previews/20437.flv?id=f48d5e8b72b04b6c60dde2639868715c',startparam: 'start',autostart: 'true',primary: 'flash',width: '640',height: '480'});</script>
```

Соответственно парсить так:

```
preg_match("#setup\({file: ['\"](.*?)['\"],#i", $cont, $matches );
```

Comment: Это точно правильно? У меня все равно не работает. 
Это ['\"] - означает что парсить ссылку нужно до знака ' ?
(.*?) - сама ссылка, да?
['\"] - начинать парсить от знака ' ?

Comment: У меня всё парсит. Тестовая страница: http://my-hit.ru/film/4427/online ['\"] - означает, что есть либо одинарная кавычка, либо двойная. После кавычки идет наш текст, а знак вопроса означает, что наш текст идет до следующей кавычки, что мы и указали.

Comment: Может тут в коде что не так, без понятия.

    /*
     * Получение плеера
     */
    
    public function get( $url = false )
    {
 $content = curl_redirect_exec( $this->ch );
 
 preg_match("#setup\({file: ['\"](.*?)['\"],#i", $content, $matches );
 
 parse_str( trim($matches[1] ), $vars );
 
 $file = $vars['file'] . '?id=' . $vars['id'];

 return array( 'file' => $file );
    }
}

Comment: @Скиталец Мэверик что у вас приходит в curl_redirect_exec( $this->ch ); ? и что возвращает var_dump($matches);

Answer (score 2):

А теперь видимо придется искать что то вида

```
preg_match( "file: ['\"](.*?)['\"]", $content, $matches );
```

Comment: да, что то типа него! 
но я перепробовал несколько вариантов, не подходит. Есть еще примеры? Делитесь!